# regex to remove the webpage part of a url in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to remove the webpage part of the URL

For example,

```
www.example.com/home/index.html
```

to

```
www.example.com/home
```

any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716513/ruby-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your heart is set on using regex and you know that your URLs will be pretty straight forward you could use `(.*)/.*` to capture everything before the last / in your URL.

```
irb(main):007:0> url = "www.example.com/home/index.html"
=> "www.example.com/home/index.html"
irb(main):008:0> regex = "(.*)/.*"
=> "(.*)/.*"
irb(main):009:0> url =~ /#{regex}/
=> 0
irb(main):010:0> $1
=> "www.example.com/home"
```

Answer (score 10):

It's probably a good idea not to use regular expressions when possible. [You may summon Cthulhu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Try using the `URI` library that's part of the standard library instead.

```
require "uri"
result = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/home/index.html")
result.host # => www.example.com
result.path # => "/home/index.html"
# The following line is rather unorthodox - is there a better solution?
File.dirname(result.path) # => "/home"
result.host + File.dirname(result.path) # => "www.example.com/home"
```

Comment: +1 URL's are not regular, cannot parse them with regex, use URI lib

Comment: Addressable::URI is another good URI module for Ruby and is a bit more full-featured. Ruby's built-in URI should be sufficient for this purpose though. http://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> url="www.example.com/home/index.html"
=> "www.example.com/home/index.html"
irb(main):002:0> url.split("/")[0..-2].join("/")
=> "www.example.com/home"
```

Comment: While this technically works, it will break on different depth URLs (/home/index.html vs /admin/users/index.html).  That's why URI.parse is better.

Comment: @Jason: Under what circumstance would `0..-2` break?

Comment: I re-read this and you're right, 0..-2 should always work.  I still vote for using URI.parse though.