# Ruby Regular expression to match a url

Tags: ruby, regex, url

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)
>   [regex to remove the webpage part of a url in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829672/regex-to-remove-the-webpage-part-of-a-url-in-ruby)

I am in search of a regular expression for parsing all the urls in a file.
i tried many of the regular expression i got after googling but it fails in one or the other case . my idea is to write one which checks the presense of http or https at the begening and it will match everything untill it sees a blank space .
any ideas ?
NOTE : i dont need to parse the url but erase all the urls from a file or atleast make it unreadable .

Comment: P.S.: where do you see Rails here? I delete this tag. Do you know difference between Ruby and Rails?

Comment: Yeah, the possible duplicates questions are hardly duplicates although one could find the good answer there `URI.parse` or `URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.make_regexp`. And I don't even see a reopen vote here.

Comment: This one is for rails but still not rails only answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/161738/520567

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try this:

```
/https?:\/\/[\S]+/
```

The `\S` means any non-whitespace character.

[(Rubular)](http://www.rubular.com/r/mA36VaphNA)

Comment: Is that really a uri regex though? That's just looking for any string that starts with http(s)... which is not a uri.

Comment: It won't work for the url `[https://google.com//]`. `[` is not a valid url character.

Comment: It won't work for urls with quotes as it will include the quotes

Answer (score 69):

The standard URI library provides `URI.regexp` which is the regular expression for url string.

```
 require 'uri'
 string.scan(URI.regexp)
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html

Comment: NB there is also a URI.extract method which basically parses all url's out of a string.  Very useful.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `string' for main:Object (NameError)
Did you mean?  String

Comment: URI.regexp seems to match strings that aren't really valid URLs such as `http://x`, or even just `http:`.

Comment: `string` is the variable you create, @FeloVilches

Comment: This matches things like `C:` too