# Need regular expression that matches url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Below is my regular expression that matches url in a text which contains regular text, url and email ids. Problem here is,it also picks up the domain part from email ids. http://rubular.com/r/imoL2yQyrO

```
/(?:(?=[\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?"'])|\b)((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9\-]+[.][a-z]{1,4}\/|[a-z0-9\-]+[.](?:[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))*(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?"']|\b))/
```

Here is the text

Is there a way to filter out the entire email id

My text

> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur, adipisci vel http://someurl.com eque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet xyz@abc.com

Matches

> http://someurl.com, abc.com

It should not match abc.com in xyz@abc.com

Comment: Does this help https?:\/\/[\S]+ from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716513/ruby-regular-expression-to-match-a-url?rq=1)

Comment: Web url? I mean that maybe you also want to match protocols like FTP, MailTo, etc.

Comment: Yes..I mean web URLs.. I wish to capture the protocol too.. Regex should also capture urls without protocols

Comment: I get an error with your Rubular link, "Premature end of char-class."

Answer (score 0):

you can post process each entry looking for an `@` sign.

```
if(ExtractedURLfromREGEX.index('@') > -1)
   ##do stuff with emails
end
```