# Ruby: Detecting broken links without actually crawling the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a Ruby gem, or Ruby-esque way to check a webpage for broken links without crawling the actual links and checking for 404's, etc. Basically, I want a solution that works offline, and I want to detect links that are obviously syntactically broken, not links that point to web pages that don't exist.

So for instance, if a link points to "http//stackoverflow.com", that's a syntactically broken link, and I want to detect that. However if a link points to "http://www.webpagedoesnotexistyet.com" and it returns a 404, I'm OK with not detecting that.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use regex. I'd check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716513/ruby-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Comment: What logic applies when relative links like `/tags` or `/users` are detected?

Comment: You'd still be using regex, first to find all `a` tags, then checking the `href` to make sure that it's either a valid full URL or begins with a `/` and doesn't include any invalid characters before the close quote. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link

Comment: [Not a regex alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex), but an XML parser to detect the `href` attribute for `<a>` tags, which then get passed through a regex.

Comment: And of course, the obligatory link to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)...

Answer (score 0):

Use nokogiri to parse the HTML and URI.parse to check for valid URLs.  URI will raise an error if it encounters what it considers to be an invalid url.

Comment: It will happily eat 'http//stackoverflow.com', though.

Answer (score 0):

Use this : Links below is an array of links

```
for link in links do
    begin
        url = URI.parse(link)
        req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
        res = req.request_head(url.path)

        if res.code == "200"
            puts "#{res.code} ok - #{link}"
        else
            puts "#{res.code} error - #{link}"
        end
    rescue
        puts "breaking for #{link}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URI.regexp`. If a string matches it, it is a valid uri.

```
require 'uri'

def valid_uri?(s)
  !!(s =~ URI.regexp)
end


valid_uri?('http//stackoverflow.com') # => false
valid_uri?('http://www.webpagedoesnotexistyet.com/') # => true
```