# Ruby URI::regexp pass colon in the website name

Tags: ruby, uri

I got a typo in a URI, i.e. colon instead of period. Why URI::regexp pass that kind of URI? For example

```
"http://www,my.com" =~ /^#{URI::regexp}$/
```

gives you 0 which means, as far as I know, it's a correct one. But if I try to parse such a URI

```
URI.parse("http://www,my.com")
```

it raises URI::InvalidURIError

Why? And how can test a URI properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation about [`URI.regexp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-regexp):

> Returns a Regexp object which matches to URI-like strings. The Regexp
>   object returned by this method includes arbitrary number of capture
>   group (parentheses). **Never rely on its number**.

Take a look at *[Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716513/ruby-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)*.

Otherwise you can use [`URI.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) and handle the relevant exception:

```
begin
  URI::parse("http://www,my.com") # => URI::InvalidURIError
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  # handle exception
end
```